# Drupal 7 don't protect word files. / private files

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

I have a one question about private files in drupal 7.

I have set private folder on my FTP. For example ../default/private-files
The system protect all images when are uploading than private file.

The problem is that the system don't protect word file.

Example:

Image

System generate link for image: ../system/files/name_of_the_image.jpg
Image is protected and i don't it downloaded.

File

System generate link for file: ../system/files/name_of_the_word_file.doc
**I can downloaded file.**

Thanks for your suggestions or tips...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've configured Drupal's private file options in:

> /admin/config/media/file-system

In:
**Default download method**

- Private local files served by Drupal (is checked).

**An important distinction:**

- Any logged in user will have access to download private files.
- Any anonymous user *will not* have access to download

If you want users to be able to download by Role, please see the module:

https://drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission

Comment: Thanks, I don't checked "Private local files served by Drupal (is checked)."